# centos 6 64bit crond not running on startup?

Tags: centos, cron

I have two VPS from ramnode, centos 6 64bit.

I have reinstalled server 2 several times and also tried 32 bit centos 6.  Same problem.  Whenever I type `reboot` and then `service crond status` it says crond is not running... despite having `chkconfig crond on` and `chkconfig --list | grep crond` shows it should start on reboot

However, if I am to do `service crond start` it runs without problems... but it should be running even after reboot.  I shouldnt have to start it.  Whats going on?

My first VPS works perfectly how I want it to.  I'm just having trouble with #2

Comment: Did you check `/var/log/messages`or `/var/log/cron`?? Perhaps there you can find more information.

Comment: Are you certain of the run-mode that is being started? (/etc/inittab). crond doesn't start in single-user mode.

Comment: run-mode is 3 and there is nothing in /var/log/cron or /var/log/messages relating to cron (i clearedthem before rebooting, cron is empty and messages has seemingly no error messages or anything relating to cron

Answer (score 0):

You can move `/etc/init.d/cron` to something like `/etc/init.d/cron_r` and create a new `/etc/init.d/cron` with something like `bash -x /etc/init.d/cron_r $1 2>&1 | logger` in it, reboot and *then* check messages log.